# How many combinations $S$ = $T \choose m$ of combinations $T$ = $n \choose k$ exist when each $p \in [1..n]$ has to appear in a subset of $S$?

Tags: combinatorics

The concrete task is this: I have a database with let's say $n = 10$ attributes. Out of these, I create subsets of dimension $k = 3$. Hence, $T$ = $n \choose k$ = 120. Thus, I have subsets like $\{1,2,3\} \in T, \{3,5,8\} \in T, \{10,3,6\} \in T$ and so on, 120 of them.

I want to execute an algorithm that takes a small set of these 120 subsets as a parameter, let's say $m = 15$ subsets. Hence, the number of choices for the parameter is $S$ = $T \choose m$ $\sim 4.7305 \cdot 10^{18}$.

Now, not all combinations for $S$ are valid as a parameter for the algorithm, since $\forall p \in [1..n]: \exists T_{sub} \in (S_{sub} \in S): p \in T_{sub}$ has to be true. Every database attribute has to be included at least once in one of those subsets, otherwise the algorithm's results produced are invalid.

In order to be able to give a few statements about certain properties of the algorithm, I let it run a few times with a different parameter randomly chosen, since it's computationally infeasible to run the algorithm for all $4.7305 \cdot 10^{18}$ possible values for its parameter. Of course it's no problem to assert that each database attribute is included at least once in one of the subsets of the algorithm's parameter.

However, the point - and my question - is: I'd like to know how many possibilities there really are for the parameter? They're definitely less than $4.7305 \cdot 10^{18}$, since there are many combinations where not every $[1..n]$ is contained in one of the $m$ subsets. How many exactly?

I cannot get my head around this, it seems to me that my problem is that I cannot come up with a clearer formulation of the situation. It seems like there might be balls each colored with k colors of a total of n colors, and building m combinations where every color is included in the end, but since no ball with one color can be independently drawn, I just don't know how to approach the problem. Any ideas?

Sorry if I couldn't make myself clear, writing up mathematical problems is not my daily business... Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{K}=\{S\subseteq[n]:|S|=k\}$, let $\Bbb M=\{\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{K}:|\mathscr{S}|=m\}$, and let $$\Bbb M_0=\{\mathscr{S}\in\Bbb M:\bigcup\mathscr{S}=[n]\}\;;$$ if I understand correctly, you want to know $|\Bbb M_0|$.

For each $\ell\in[n]$ let $\mathscr{K}_\ell=\{S\in\mathscr{K}:\ell\notin S\}$; $\mathscr{S}\in\Bbb M\setminus\Bbb M_0$ if and only if there is at least one $\ell\in[n]$ such that $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{K}_\ell$. We can therefore apply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to find that

$$\begin{align*}
|\Bbb M_0|&=\binom{\binom{n}k}m-n\binom{\binom{n-1}k}m+\binom{n}2\binom{\binom{n-2}k}m-+\ldots\\
&=\sum_i(-1)^i\binom{n}i\binom{\binom{n-i}k}m\;.
\end{align*}$$

This helps very little in your example:

$$\binom{120}{15}=4\,730\,523\,156\,632\,595\,024\;,$$

and

$$|\Bbb M_0|=4\,583\,146\,555\,978\,704\,864\;,$$

which is smaller by less than $3.12$%.

Comment: Great, thank you for your explanation! The one link I missed in your otherwise exhaustive description is "what is it exactly I add again after the first subtraction", but I think these are the elements counted too much that miss not only **one** $\ell\in[n]$, but **two** of them, right? And so on? If my understanding is correct (though maybe clumsily stated), all is well and the reason I had trouble with you omitting this fact is rooted in my insufficient understanding of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @stef77: Yes, your understanding is correct. You’re welcome!